# What is the best algorithm for restoring the state of a navigation stack

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I don't know the best way to let an App restore the navigation controller stack so that the app will re-launch in the same way that it was exited.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1811696/how-to-preserve-iphone-application-state-before-terminating-the-application) :)

Sam

Answer (score 0):

If it is a navigation controller stack, then that hierarchy usually dictates that there is only one way to reach a particular item.

So you don't really need any algorithm, simply store the item ID (or any other state sent to the current view controller) in the user prefs.