# Home button event

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I do not want close my app when user press home button.Instead of that I need to go back to the same page where I left after reopening the app.

Comment: can you please explain a little bit ?

Comment: If your are talking about home button of iPhone, then its not possible and if you are talking about your app home button then please explain more about your problem.

Comment: i am talking about iphone home button.

Comment: i have no points to accept your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using the other view controller than use this function for close button.

For older version:

```
-(IBAction)Close:(id)sender{
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

For iOS6:

```
-(IBAction)closebtn:(id)sender{
{
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:Nil];
}
```

It will automatically redirect you to the view controller from where it is navigated to current view controller.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to save the state of the app when it goes into the background and then retrieve it when it comes to foreground. Try reading about `NSUserDefaults`. Here is the documentation [link](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsuserdefaults_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

Comment: @karthi You can go through [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1811696/how-to-preserve-iphone-application-state-before-terminating-the-application?answertab=active#tab-top) of somewhat similar other Stack Overflow question too. It might help only

Answer (score 0):

These are your options

In your app delegate:

```
- (void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application
{
    // Sent when the application is about to move from active to inactive state. This can occur for certain types of temporary interruptions (such as an incoming phone call or SMS message) or when the user quits the application and it begins the transition to the background state.
    // Use this method to pause ongoing tasks, disable timers, and throttle down OpenGL ES frame rates. Games should use this method to pause the game.
}

- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
{
    // Use this method to release shared resources, save user data, invalidate timers, and store enough application state information to restore your application to its current state in case it is terminated later. 
    // If your application supports background execution, this method is called instead of applicationWillTerminate: when the user quits.
}

- (void)applicationWillTerminate:(UIApplication *)application
{
    // Called when the application is about to terminate. Save data if appropriate. See also applicationDidEnterBackground:.
}

- (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application
{
    // Called as part of the transition from the background to the inactive state; here you can undo many of the changes made on entering the background.
}

- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application
{
    // Restart any tasks that were paused (or not yet started) while the application was inactive. If the application was previously in the background, optionally refresh the user interface.
}
```

These methods are called in particular sequence when user press the Home Button. Your application doesn't stop. It goes in background. You can write your logic in these function to make sure your application opens in the same class where it stopped.

Answer (score 0):

The iPhone/iPad home button always closes the current application and returns to the home screen. This behavior cannot be overridden by applications.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're talking about the physical home button. Apple sandboxes all applications except their own, therefore you cannot access certain aspects of iDevices, all hardware buttons included. If you want the application to return where the user left off after it enters the background, you would use the method in the delegate files i.e.

```
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application {// your code}
```

If your question relates just to returning to where the user left off in a different kind of sense (and again the physical home button)...

Like Zen said, you can use user defaults if you want, say, a certain text field to be filled the next time the user goes to fill it out. i.e.

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

if (!defaults) {
    [self setDefaults]; // where setDefaults is just a method that set some random values
}

int apples = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] integerForKey:@"apples"];
if (apples == 0) {
    apples = 2;
}

// fill in the interface values for xibApples, a UITextField outlet
[xibApples setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", apples]];
```